# Inequality Proof by Induction involving Euler Totient function and Summation of Euler's Phi function

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, induction, totient-function

I want to Prove the following result using induction:

Show that P$_n$:
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)+2 \geq \frac{12(n-1)^2}{\pi^2}\label{eq:15}
\end{equation}
for all $n,k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, where the product is over all prime factors of $k$.

Proof:

P$_1$ case: For $n = 2$ we get,
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{k=1}^2 \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)+2 \geq \frac{12(2-1)^2}{\pi^2} \implies 4 \geq \frac{12}{\pi^2}, \hspace{2em} \text{P$_1$ is True.} 
\end{equation}

P$_\alpha$ case: Suppose Eqn\eqref{eq:15} holds for some $\alpha$ s.t.
\begin{equation}2\sum_{k=1}^\alpha \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)+2 \geq \frac{12(\alpha-1)^2}{\pi^2} ,\hspace{2em} \forall (\alpha,k) \in \mathbb{Z}_+. \label{eq:17}
\end{equation}

P$_{\alpha + 1}$ case: Now consider that it holds for some $\alpha$ + 1,
\begin{equation} 2\sum_{k=1}^{\alpha + 1} \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)+2 \geq \frac{12((\alpha +1)-1)^2}{\pi^2},\hspace{2em} \label{eq:18}
\end{equation}

Simplifying and expanding the LHS and RHS we get,
\begin{equation} 2\left(\underbrace{\prod_{p \vert 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) + ... + \prod_{p \vert \alpha}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)}_{\text{using} \ \text{P}_\alpha} + \prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right) \right)+2 \geq \frac{12\alpha^2}{\pi^2} ,\hspace{2em} \label{eq:19}
\end{equation}
Therefore we get, \begin{equation}
\left[2\sum_{k=1}^\alpha \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) \right]+2 \geq \frac{12\alpha^2}{\pi^2} ,\hspace{2em} \label{eq:20}
\end{equation}

We are assuming that Eqn\eqref{eq:17} is true so, if we replace $\Phi(\alpha)$
in the above expression with the smaller number $\frac{12(\alpha-1)^2}{\pi^2}$, we produce a smaller result. So:
\begin{equation}2\sum_{k=1}^\alpha \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2 \geq\frac{12(\alpha-1)^2}{\pi^2} + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2. \label{eq:21}
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{equation}
\frac{12(\alpha-1)^2}{\pi^2} + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2 = \frac{12(2-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2}. \label{eq:22}
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{k=1}^\alpha \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2 \geq \frac{12(2-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2} \label{eq:23}
\end{equation}
Since $\alpha$ $\geq$ 1, we know that $\frac{12(2-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2}$ $\geq$ 0, so
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{k=1}^\alpha \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2 \geq \frac{12(\alpha-1)^2}{\pi^2} \geq 0 \label{eq:24}
\end{equation}
Or,
\begin{equation}
2\Phi(\alpha) + \varphi(\alpha + 1) + 2 \geq \frac{12(\alpha-1)^2}{\pi^2} \geq 0 \label{eq:25}
\end{equation}
Where,
\begin{equation}
\Phi(\alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^\alpha \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\varphi(\alpha + 1) = \prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)
\end{equation}
Hence, by the principle of mathematical induction, P$_n$ is true for all integers
$\alpha \geq 1$.

Q.E.D

## Question

I know I have made a mistake in this proof and is definitely not correct but Im not sure what I've done wrong, I think the error is in this part,
\begin{equation}
\frac{12(\alpha-1)^2}{\pi^2} + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2 = \frac{12(2-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
2\sum_{k=1}^\alpha \left(\prod_{p \vert k}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2 \geq \frac{12(2-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2}
\end{equation}
Since $\alpha\geq 1$, we know that $\frac{12(2-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2} \geq 0$, so, what mistake did I make and how should I fix it?

Comment: What you call $P_1$ (and is in fact $P(2)$) is not "$\Rightarrow4\ge\frac{12}{\pi^2}$" but $\Leftrightarrow5\ge\frac{12}{\pi^2}.$

Answer (score 4):

It is worse than a "mistake": it is a *non-justified claim*:
$$\frac{12(\alpha-1)^2}{\pi^2} + 2\left(\prod_{p \vert \alpha + 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\right) + 2 = \frac{12(2-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2},$$
which is *obviously false* by irrationality of $\pi.$

Your "proof" essentially consists in this claim and is *unsalvageable*. Your "Result" *cannot be proved by a simple induction* because it would require, for every integer $\alpha\ge2$:
$$2\prod_{p\mid\alpha+1}\left(1-\frac1p\right)\ge\frac{12(\alpha^2-(\alpha-1)^2)}{\pi^2},$$
which is false for every prime $\alpha+1.$

**Even your "Result" itself is grossly false**: test $P(4),$ or realize that the LHS of your $P(n)$ is $\le2n+2.$